# AngleSharp click div

Tags: c#, html, click, anchor, anglesharp

In AngleSharp `IHtmlAnchorElement` has  `DoClick()` method.
In my case I need to click a `div`. How can I do it?

**HTML:**

```
<div role="button" class="div"></div>
```

**C#:**

```
IHtmlAnchorElement anc = document.Anchors.First(x => x.ClassName == "anc");
anc.DoClick();
IElement div = document.All.First(x => x.ClassName == "div");
//! DoClick on div?
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa, I did, but found no answer.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Look into the code i foundout that the `IHtmlElement` interfaces is the one that holds the `DoClick();` Method.

That Interface documentation says:

> **The HTMLElement interface represents any HTML element. Some elements directly implement this interface, other implement it via an interface that inherit it.**

So it actually is fitting for your needs, rather than the more Abstract interface `IElement` which `IHtmlElement` inherits from.

This should make it appear.

```
IHtmlElement div = document.All.First(x => x.ClassName == "div");
div.DoClick();
```